# No Signal Shown in Isim simulation

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise, digital

i am working on a vhdl code which is supposed to do many functionalities.my code and also my test bench are working fine. but in simulation nothing is initialized. and i dont really understand why and where exactly is my mistake.i would appreciate if someone help me with my problem.
"the code should work when enable is '1' and in rising_edge clk. and with different values of S it should do different things.

errors on my simulation are:

ERROR: at 0 ps: Delay 20000 fs is not greater than previous waveform element delay 20000 fs in assignment for target signal a
ERROR: In process MyProject_tb.vhd:34

my code is:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY ALU IS
   port(
      A : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        B : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
      enable : IN STD_LOGIC;
        clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
      s : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
        carry : OUT STD_LOGIC;
      c : INOUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)   
   );
END ALU;


ARCHITECTURE Project of ALU is

signal mult : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
signal temp : std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);

begin
     p1: PROCESS(enable, clk, s)
     BEGIN
            IF (enable = '1' AND (clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') AND s = "00") THEN
                 -- cyclic shift on B
                  carry <= '0';
                  c(0) <= B(3);
                    l1: FOR i IN 1 TO 3 LOOP
                       c(i) <= B(i-1);
                              END LOOP;
                END IF;
        END PROCESS;
        
        p2 : PROCESS(enable, clk, s)
        BEGIN
             IF (enable = '1') THEN
                    IF (clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
                     IF (s = "01") THEN
                        --Multiply A and B  
                        c <= "0000";                      
                        carry <= '0';
                        mult <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(A) * unsigned(B));
                              c <= ("0000" & c);
                        c <= mult;
                            END IF;
                        END IF;
                  END IF;
                END PROCESS;
        p3: PROCESS(enable, clk, s)
        BEGIN
            IF (enable = '1') THEN
                IF (clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
                    IF (s = "10") THEN
                     --Two's Compliment of A
                     carry <= '0';
                     temp <= not A;
                     c <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp) + 1);
                        END IF;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END PROCESS;
        p4: PROCESS(A , B, enable, clk, s)
        BEGIN
            IF (enable = '1') THEN
                IF (clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
                       IF (s = "11") THEN
                     --4-bit Comparator
                     c <= "0011";
                     IF (unsigned(A) > unsigned(B)) THEN
                         c <= "1111";
                     elsif (unsigned(A) < unsigned(B)) THEN
                         c <= "0000";
                     END IF;
                        END IF;
                    END IF;
             END IF;
          END PROCESS;
end Project;
```

and also my test bench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

ENTITY alu_test IS
END alu_test;

    ARCHITECTURE test of alu_test IS
       COMPONENT ALU IS
          port(
          A : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
          B : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
          enable : IN STD_LOGIC;
          clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
          s : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
          carry : OUT STD_LOGIC;
          c : INOUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)   
       );
       END COMPONENT;
    
    SIGNAL a : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    SIGNAL b : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    SIGNAL c : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    SIGNAL s : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0) := "00";
    SIGNAL en : STD_LOGIC := '1';
    SIGNAL cl : STD_LOGIC := '1';
    SIGNAL car : STD_LOGIC;
    
    BEGIN
       uut : ALU PORT MAP(a, b ,en, cl, s , car, c);
    en <= '1';
    cl <= not cl AFTER 20 NS;
    a <= "0001" , "1101" AFTER 20 NS, "1110" AFTER 20 NS;
    b <= "1101" , "0101" AFTER 20 NS, "1111" AFTER 20 NS;
    s <= "01" , "00" AFTER 20 NS, "10" AFTER 20 NS;
    
    END test;
```

and its how my simulation looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpXvV.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], here context clauses (library clause(s), use clauses) for ALU and alu_test and the entity declaration for alu_test.

Comment: A minimal, reproducible example would also include any console error messages and warnings as text in the question [e.g. for a recent ghdl release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g17iv.jpg). You code neither successfully analyzes (compiles), elaborates (links and loads)  nor runs (simulate). The warning reflects an anticipated run time error and should be addressed. The errors need to be corrected.

Comment: @user1155120 my mistake. i edited my codes.

Comment: The errors are from the standard (e.g. IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement "...the evaluation of a waveform results in a sequence of transactions, where each transaction corresponds to one waveform element in the waveform. These transactions are called *new* transactions. It is an error if the sequence of new transactions is not in ascending order with respect to time.") Incremental time from the time the assignment takes place.

Comment: For the warning, C has 4 elements while the result from the "*" result has a length equal to the length of the left operand added to the length of the right operand (8). 14.7.3.4 Signal update "For a composite signal R, an implicit subtype conversion is performed to the subtype of R; for each element of R, there shall be a matching element in both the driving and the effective value, and vice versa." (during simulation).

Comment: *i edited my codes*.  Edit your question.

Comment: Synopsys package std_logic_unsigned and IEEE package numeric_std shouldn't be used together. You don't depend on declarations in package std_logic_unsigned in either ALU or alu_test and nor package numeric_std in alu_test.

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
 a <= "0001" , "1101" AFTER 20 NS, "1110" AFTER 20 NS;
 b <= "1101" , "0101" AFTER 20 NS, "1111" AFTER 20 NS;
 s <= "01" , "00" AFTER 20 NS, "10" AFTER 20 NS;
```

don't do what you most likely expect them to do.

You most likely want a sequence of "0001", "1101" & "1110" for signal `a` with 20 ns in between. Otherwise (as the error message suggests), you would assign both "1101" and "1110" to `a` at the same time (after 20 ns), which is not possible. So reformat your lines to something like:

```
a <= "0001" , "1101" AFTER 20 NS, "1110" AFTER 40 NS;
```

I would prefer using a `wait` statement (inside a process) for wiggling the stimulus signals, though, e.g.:

```
process
begin
    a <= "0001";
    wait for 20 ns;
    a <= "1101";
    -- and so on...
```

After this there are some errors revealed in your design (ALU) but fixing them would be another question...

Comment: thanks alot. yes i almost fixed all of the errors except one error that i dont know is it possible to be fixed or not.  i declared my output 'c' to be 4 bit.and somewhere in my code i need it to be 8 bits(when A*B). and its impossible to do it i guess. should i have another output for my multiply result or maybe there is a way to show it with my 4bit output?

Comment: That's another question. I suggest opening a new question and pinpointing the problem there.